# sub query in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables :

```
create table sales (
    unitcode int ,
    categorycode smallint ,
    ddate varchar(10) ,
    price float
)
```

and

```
create table timetable (
    year varchar(4) ,
    month varchar(11) ,
    ddate varchar(10)
)
```

I want to write a subquery to find :
 in each month in each year which 2 products(unitcode , categorycode) have a top of price ?

Comment: Your descriptions were *so close* to being actual DDL that I've converted them to be so (I've also formatted as code).

Comment: I want to write subquery in order to find this question : een eech month of eech year which 2 products had max price ?

Comment: look :  
SELECT TOP 2 s.UnitCode , s.CategoryCode , t.DDate , s.Price 
FROM Sales s inner join TimeTable t
ON s.DDate = t.DDate
WHERE t.[Month] = 'may'and t.[Year] = '2001'
ORDER BY t.[Month] ASC , s.Price DESC

Comment: but I have 3 different years : 2001 , 2002 , 2003 , how can i show 2 max price of all months in these 3 years?

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  unitcode,categorycode,t.ddate,price,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.[year],t.[month] ORDER BY price desc) AS price_order,t.[year],t.[month]
FROM  sales s 
INNER JOIN timetable t 
    ON t.ddate = s.ddate
)
SELECT  *
FROM    cte
WHERE price_order <= 2
ORDER BY [year] ASC,[month] ASC,price DESC
```

Comment: thanks a lot Mr.EricZ , thanks , it is very very wonderful and interesting and beautiful , thanks

Comment: I want to solve above query with CURSER , can any one help me?

Comment: @SOHEILA DALIRI, any reason why you have to do this with CURSOR?